# 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to use class based views, and get a strange error. The way I'm using the view seems to be the normal way:

ingredients/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def get_prices():
        purchases   = self.purchase_set.all()
        prices      = [purchase.price for purchase in purchases]
```

ingredients/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts           import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.http                import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.edit  import CreateView
from .models                    import Ingredient, Purchase

def IngredientCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Ingredient
    fields = ['all']
```

ingredients/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from ingredients.views import IngredientCreateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',            
    url(r'^new_ingredient$',          IngredientCreateView.as_view(),             name='new-ingredient'),
)
```

I get

```
AttributeError at /ingredients/new_ingredient
'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

I am on django 1.8.5. Why won't this view work? Thank you

Comment: In my case I was giving same name to `viewset` and `model`. Giving them different name solved my problem

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`IngredientCreateView` should be a class.
So your views.py replace:

```
def IngredientCreateView(CreateView):
```

with:

```
class IngredientCreateView(CreateView):
```

Comment: In my case I was giving same name to `viewset` and `model`. Giving them different name solved my problem

Comment: I had been staring at the files so long I didn't even see that. 

Answer (score 62):

In my case, the problem was that I tried to use a @decorator on the class-based view as if it was a function-based view, instead of [@decorating the class correctly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

EDIT: From the linked page, here is a way to apply @login_required to a class-based view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
```

Comment: Thank you I actually made the mistake of @csrf_exept decorator and hence it was failing

Comment: can i ask you please what is name='dispatch' ? what do you mean

Comment: @KokHyvv When you decorate the class, you're actually decorating a function within the class, in this case the 'dispatch' function which runs the view. Since the dispatch function is inherited, its name only appears here in the decorator.

Comment: aha okay i understand you thanks for explain

Answer (score 10):

`IngredientCreateView` is a function, not a class.

The following line

```
def IngredientCreateView(CreateView):
```

should be replace with

```
class IngredientCreateView(CreateView):
```

Comment: idk whose was first, but thank you. old habits die hard, gotta get used to class views :)

Answer (score 4):

```
def Some_def_View(CreateView):
```

#should be replaced with

```
class SomeClassView(CreateView)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what is already said here, Check the file name and class name if it is same then you might have to import the class properly.

```
File name /api/A.py

class A:
//some methods
```

In your main class

```
//App main class
from api.A import A
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem but this solution worked for me..

in **views.py** file in viewclass you can use viewsets instead of CreateView

```
            from rest_framework import viewsets
            class YourClassView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
```

in **urls.py** file you can use this routing pattern

```
          from django.conf.urls import url
          from rest_framework import routers

          router = routers.DefaultRouter()
          router.register('books',YourClassView)

          urlpatterns = [
               path('', include(router.urls)),
               path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
            ]
```